# CA2W gave me a "'AtlThrowLastWin32': identifier not found" error

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-studio-2005, atl, big5

I got a strange compilation error when I followed the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.80).aspx) to use CA2W to convert big5 strings to unicode strings in Visual Studio 2005.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <string>
#include <atldef.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string chineseInBig5 = "\xA4\xA4\xA4\xE5";
    ATL::CA2W(chineseInBig5.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error: error C3861: 'AtlThrowLastWin32': identifier not found

I don't know how this could happen. The [document of AtlThrowLastWin32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3a80dsf.aspx) shows that atldef.h is required, but I couldn't find the declaration of AtlThrowLastWin32 in atldef.h.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by adding 2 include headers:

```
#include <atlbase.h> 
#include <atlstr.h>
```

I don't know why the MSDN document doesn't mention that.

Comment: MSDN (on the page you linked to) says: 
> Requirements

> Header file: AtlBase.h, AtlConv.h (declared in AtlConv.h)

Comment: Thanks to Logan Capaldo. I finally found why I was confused. The document of CA2AEX (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0d7hetw(VS.80).aspx) only mentions "Requirements Header: atlconv.h"