# Error in including atlconv.h in VS 15.7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

We have a legacy code that uses ATL that was running fine on Windows until we used VS2017 15.6. When we upgraded to 15.7, we started hitting the following compilation error:

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\atlmfc\include\atlconv.h(395): error C3861: 'AtlThrowLastWin32': identifier not found

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\atlmfc\include\atlconv.h(406): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'ATL::CA2WEX' being compiled

A quick search found the following link: https://naughter.wordpress.com/2017/01/02/a-comprehensive-comparison-of-the-mfc-atl-changes-in-vs-2017-rc-compared-to-visual-studio-2015-update-3-part-1/

which has the following information:

Line 91: Minor change to comment to fix spelling mistake

Line 94: AtlThrowImpl is now declared as __declspec(noreturn)

Line 112: AtlThrowLastWin32 is now declared as __declspec(noreturn)

We are using both

> define _ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS
>
> define _ATL_CUSTOM_THROW

Has anyone successfully compiled a C++ project that includes ATL on latest VS (15.7) with _ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS and _ATL_CUSTOM_THROW turned on?

Comment: Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you post questions

Comment: Seems unlikely, nothing in the question to give somebody a chance to repro the problem.  There is an [exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1083252/17034) from 2009, fumbled #includes.